# ionic-vuejs: how to remove this extra space above ion-label when using ion-item fill="outline" and ion-label position="floating"?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

[here's the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH6IA.png)

[here's the style when input is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkV8t.png)

Here's my code:

```
<ion-item fill="outline">
   <ion-icon :src="mail" slot="start"></ion-icon>
   <ion-label position="floating">Email Address</ion-label>
   <ion-input placeholder="Enter text"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

I am using ionic framework and vue.js as a javascript framework. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The extra space above the `<ion-label>` is present because the text inside the tag is going to move there when clicked.
In case you want the Icon and the text of the label on one level you can easily achieve this by repositioning the Icon itself.

```
<style>
ion-icon{
   margin-block-start: auto;
}
</style>
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3opnlh-qaob7k?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FExample.vue).